# How to increase software rendering video performance in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, virtualscroll

Let's assume I have a thousand of object array which includes `.mp4` came from cloudinary. I've also tried to transform into `.webm` type to compress file sizes but somehow it still didn't much reduce the performance.

How can I optimize the performance of my software when rendering thousands of video objects with video URLs fetched from Cloudinary?

Our rendering use case is pretty much similar with youtube.

I would like to render my list of videos like the way youtube does, have also implemented virtual scroller but it didn't much reduce the performance. Probably I was rendering a certian list of video at once. Any suggestion? :)

[image]

I wonder what does that disk cache mean? can we clean up those caches? Or is there anything that we can do?

And what does `63 requests | 0 B transferred | 25.3 MB resources` indicate? Is that a problem for performance?

Comment: The question is too unspecific for SO and may be closed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . "but it didn't work properly as expected" - throwing away a solution half-way and asking for a vague alternative isn't constructive. What did you try and what did not work? You obviously don't need to render all videos at once in case this is the case, and probably render a video only when it's clicked/hovered. You can check the way it works on YT, etc, to make sure a list of videos is actually just a list of thumb images, that can be further optimized by using virtual scroll

Comment: Yeah I was trying to implement like the way YT does :) I apologize for not clarifying my question earlier due to some limitations in my English skills :P

Comment: Check what HTML looks like on YT and when exactly the assets is loaded in devtools "network", should give a good idea on what happens there

Comment: Why do you want to render thousands of videos? I haven't seen a single Youtube site that does the same thing. Is this a browser problem, or a server-side problem?

Comment: I initially fetch a large array of thousands of objects upon the first load and store it. What I'm aiming to achieve is rendering only the elements currently visible within the viewport. I'd like to load and display additional items as the user scrolls through the list.

Comment: You probably shouldn't fetch thousands of objects at once. Similar to your goal of rendering a few at a time, you should aim to only fetch a few at a time as well.  Virtual scroll works very well for this kind of problem.  There are tons of working code examples, tutorials and libraries out there. Not knowing anything about _your_ code or implementation attempt, it'd be hard for anyone to offer any more specific advice.

Comment: I added my network image! If you don't mind, can anyone explain to my above questions, please!